# SqlDataReader Close and SqlConnection

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

What happens with the connection in this case? I don't know if reader.Close() close the open sqlconnection.

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the reader will not alter the state of the connection. If you did want to do this you can pass `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` to the `ExecuteReader` method of the `SqlCommand` instance.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

It is recommended you put a `using` block around all your disposable types like your `SqlDataReader` instance.

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
  // rest of code
}
```

See also [CommandBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) for more options.

Answer (score 3):

reader.Close() won't close the SqlConnection, but since you have a *using* statement, once you exit the using block the connection will get closed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Connection State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Close();
}
connection.Open();
```

And since you are doing

```
using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
```

this will make sure connection is disposed as it inherits from IDisposable despite Exception. And object are disposed once they exit their corresponding scope.

And better use

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
```

and

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

for the same reason mentioned above.